# How to tag a person to a photo on a facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to tag a person to a photo that has been posted to a Facebook page (not profile).

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{PHOTO_ID}/tags?to={PERSON_ID}&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

The above works if the Photo_ID is one that has been posted to a profile, however, if I use the id of a photo that was posted to a page then I get

```
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#322) Invalid photo tag subject"
```

I've tried using the Authenticated User's Access Token as well as the Page Access Token (as the documentation states) both produce the same error response.

I'm using the following scopes
`publish_stream,photo_upload,manage_pages,user_photos`

Is this even possible? If so, what in the world am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `user_photos` permission to tag a photo, so I guess it cannot work with page!

Comment: I'm just surprised it doesn't give a permission error, and instead gives a "Invalid photo tag subject".

Comment: Do you know of a way (or if) to request facebook allow this?